# How can I get an instance of a subclass of abstract class from a static method of another class?

Tags: java, static, abstract-class, subclass, instance-variables

I have the following class structure:

- DataStore classes:

  - Parent class: `PStore`:  `public abstract class PStore ...`
  - 2 child classes extending it: `CStore1` and `CStore2`
  - Each of the child classes is a N-glton (sorry, not sure what Java term for that is) - it can have only N instances, numbered 1..NMax.
  - Each child class has the following methods for accessing that instance: `CStore1.getInstance(Id)` and `CStore2.getInstance(Id)`
- Worker classes:

  - Parent class: `public abstract class PWork...`
  - 2 child classes extending it: `CWork1` and `CWork2`
- Current situation:

  - Class `CWork1` implemented an inner class with the following code accessing the Store:

    ```
    protected class fListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                CStore1.getInstance(Id).someMethod();
                # NOTE: someMethod() is implemented in CStore2 as well
            }
        }
    ```
  - I need to implement the same `fListener` class in `CWork2`
  - Being a good little software developer, instead of simply copy/pasting `fListener` from `CWork1` to `CWork2` class and then changing `CStore1` to `CStore2` in its code, I decided like an idiot to migrate it to a parent class.

---

- What I tried to do:

  - Create an abstract method in `PStore` called `getStoreInstance(int Id)`: `public abstract PStore getStoreInstance(int Id);`
  - Implement that method in `CStore1` as `public PStore getStoreInstance(int Id) { return CStore1.getInstance(Id); }`

    So far, so good. It compiled all 3 Store classes.
  - Copy the fListener code from `PWork` to `CWork1` class
  - Obviously, the compiler complained that it does not know anything about CStore1 class and its method `getStoreInstance()`
  - Now, I decided to simply call the newly created `getStoreInstance()`:

    Old code: `CStore1.getInstance(Id).someMethod();`

    New code: `PStore.getStoreInstance(Id).someMethod();`
- **Compiler complaint**: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getStoreInstance(Id) from the type PStore".
- The only "fix" proposed by Eclipse was to make getStoreInstance() method static, but THAT didn't work either:

  - When I added a `static` modifier to the abstract classes's declaration of the method: `public static abstract PStore getStoreInstance(int Id);` - the compiler complained that "The abstract method getStoreInstance in type PStore can only set a visibility modifier, one of public or protected"
  - When I tried to make the method non-abstract: `public static PStore getStoreInstance(int Id);` it complained that the method needed a body (quite sensibly)
  - When I tried to add a body, it required me to return PStore object... BUT!!!! My abstract class PStore has no constructore, so there's no way I can return PStore object!!!

---

**Am I approaching the problem correctly?**

**If not, how should I approach it?**

**If I am, then how can I resolve the original complaint** about "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method", in light of the fact that the abstract class isn't letting me make that method static?

Comment: This is very difficult to follow.  Rather than trying to describe your code, why not just construct a short code example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: `cannot make a static reference to the non-static method` is a very common error. I hope you understand what it means.

Comment: I have my doubts about how you retrieve a `CStoreX` instance. You say you have the instance method `CStore1.getInstance(Id)`; this isn't very logic to get an instance from that. Can you add a code sample so it is easier to have an overview?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - yes. I just don't know how to fix it since I can't seem to make the method static (obvious fix) because it's in an abstract class.

Comment: Is the only difference between the workers which pstore they use?

Comment: @Bohemian - There are other differences but they don't affect the Action listener. I assume you were going to propose getting rid of 2 worker classes and do some sort of dynamic dispatch for the store from the generic one?

Comment: No. It can be done without too much Kung Fu. If workers have other differences it just means an extra abstract worker class to do it "properly", but I'll post as if they're the same - you can create subclasses of worker as needed. I'm on the train right now, and there's a bit too much code to type on an iPhone, so give me an hour or so to post a solution. Don't panic... It can be done!

Comment: I'm not clear on why you did this: "Copy the `fListener` code from `PWork` to `CWork1` class".  I thought the object was to avoid duplicated code in `CWork1` and `CWork2`, which is why you wanted to put it in the parent class `PWork` in the first place--so why are you moving it back to `CWork1`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ajb - sorry, that was a typo. Should have said "move", not "copy"

Comment: Still don't understand--did you get it backwards?  I.e. should it be move from `CWork1` to `PWork`, so that it's in one place that can be called from both child classes?

Answer (score 1):

The way it looks to me, you have two class hierarchies that are isomorphic (if I'm using the right term) and there is a relationship between the corresponding classes:

```
      PStore                   PWork
      /     \                 /     \
     /       \               /       \
   CStore1  CStore2        CWork1   CWork2
      ^         ^              ^      ^  
      |         |              |      | 
      |---------+--------------|      |
                |                     |
                |---------------------|
```

But I don't think there's a built-in way to express this kind of relationship in Java.
Somehow, you're going to have to do something that makes those relationships explicit.  I.e. there will need to be something in `CWork1` that refers to `CStore1`, and something in `CWork2` that refers to `CStore2`, or else some kind of list or map that associates them.

There's probably a design pattern that addresses this structure, but I can't think of it right now.  So off the top of my head, here are a couple possible solutions (neither of which uses reflection):

1. Put the abstract `getStoreInstance` method you defined in `PWork` instead of `PStore`.  In `CWork1`, override it with a method that calls `CStore1.getInstance`, and similarly in `CWork2`.  Then the common `fListener` `actionPerformed` code would call `getStoreInstance(Id).someMethod()`, with no class name, which would work on the current `PWork` instance.  You would still have some "duplicated" code (since you'd have to implement `getStoreInstance` in both `CWork` classes), but it would be kept to a minimum.
2. Set up a map.  This compiles (Java 8), but I haven't tested it:

   ```
   class PWork {

       private static Map<Class<? extends PWork>,IntFunction<PStore>> storeMap;
       static {
           storeMap = new HashMap<>();
           storeMap.put(CWork1.class, CStore1::getInstance);
           storeMap.put(CWork2.class, CStore2::getInstance);
       }

       protected PStore getStoreInstance(int Id) {
           return storeMap.get(getClass()).apply(Id);
       }

       protected class fListener implements ActionListener {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              int Id = ???; // I'm assuming Id is computed from ae somehow??
              getStoreInstance(Id).someMethod();
          }
       }

    }
   ```

Now `getStoreInstance` looks in the map, using the current `PWork` object's class (`CWork1` or `CWork2`) as a key, to figure out which `getInstance` static method to call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with a static method on PStore and not having repeated code.

Make your worker generic, keeping a class token reference, and invoke

```
public class Worker<T extends PStore> {
    private final Class<T> c;
    public Worker(Class<T> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        PStore.getInstance(c, Id).someMethod();
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Now for the static method in PStore, which doesn't have to be a generic method: The worker doesn't have to know the actual type returned, it just will be the right type.

```
public class PStore {
    private static Map<Class<?>, List<PStore>> map = new HashMap<>();

    protected PStore() {
        List<PStore> list = map.get(getClass());
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(getClass(), list);
        }
        list.add(this);
    }

    public static PStore getInstance(Class<? extends PStore> c, int i) {
        return map.get(c).get(i);
    }
    public abstract void someMethod();
}
```

The benefit here is that the capping of N instances is left to the PStore subclass. Also notice how the list contains PStore instances, which are actually subclass instances, but neither PStore nor the worker cares (as long as it is actually the desired subclass returned, which it will be).

Disclaimer: I typed this in on my phone, so it might not compile - let me know if there's a problem and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Is `map` supposed to be static?  Other than that, compiles OK assuming `Id` (in actionPerformed) and `someMethod()` (in `PStore`) are defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct in that making a reference to an instance method in a static context doesn't work. In the static world, you're working on a class level and dealing with properties of entire classes. If you try to call an instance method, how does the compiler know what instance you want to perform the instance method?

Making an abstract method doesn't work because abstract methods must be implemented in subclasses. However, static methods cannot be overridden -- only hidden. So if `static` were allowed on abstract methods, and you tried to do `AbstractClass.staticMethod()`, what implementation would the runtime use?

Your code is somewhat hard to follow, but here's what I think. Just based on the name, `getStoreInstance(int Id)` should indeed be a static method, because it doesn't make much sense for an instance to get another instance; that seems more like something that the class should do. You might want to rethink how you're structuring your code... From the code names, it seems like you should have a class-level way of tracking instances of the class, so maybe doing something like that and implementing `getInstance()` and `getStoreInstance()` as static methods would be a start?

Comment: That's **exactly what I tried to do** - make `getStoreInstance(int  Id)` static -see the last 2 bullets in the question. Obviously, the way I tried to make it static was wrong, so what's the right way?

Comment: @DVK Sorry, I must have missed those points. What it seems is that you'll need to rethink how you're doing this. One thing you can do is determine what types of stores have what IDs, and based on the ID return a specific store, something like that. That way you can return a subclass of a `PStore` and make the method work.

Comment: @DVK Either that or add another parameter that tells you the type of store you want to return.

Comment: How will it help me create a static method?

Comment: @DVK Because in that way it's possible to return an object of type `PStore`, right? I can almost guarantee that Bohemian's code will be better than my way though... I'm just trying to do something that'll leave your code as intact as possible.

Comment: leaving code intact is always admirable, but I'm open to drastic solutions. Like porting the whole thing to Perl :)

Comment: @DVK I think ajb did better than I would have suggested. What Bohemian posts will probably work better than what I would have suggested too.